# Android Create JSONobject from Sqlite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, multidimensional-array, json

I am tring to create a JSON object from a Sqlite database, with limited success.

Here are a few example records:

```
ConditionID : 1196
VariableValue : 25
Operator : ==
VariableCondition : 74
GroupCondition : 1

ConditionID : 1195
VariableValue : 26
Operator : ==
VariableCondition : 74
GroupCondition : 1

ConditionID : 1198
VariableValue : 27
Operator : ==
VariableCondition : 74
GroupCondition : 1
```

And my expected JSON object:

```
// key : value
"1196":
{
    "1":
    {
        "0": {"VariableValue":"25","Operator":"==","VariableCondition":"74"}
    }
},
"1195":
{
    "1":
    {
        "0": {"VariableValue":"26","Operator":"==","VariableCondition":"74"}
    }
},
"1198":
{
    "1":
    {
        "0":{"VariableValue":"27","Operator":"==","VariableCondition":"74"}
    }
}
```

I have tried this following code to generate the jsonObject

```
JSONArray jsonArrayConditionDetail = null;

    JSONObject jsonConditionDetail = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonConditionGroup = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonConditionIndex = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonConditionValue = new JSONObject();
    String strConditionID = "" ,strConditionGroup = "";
    List<DataConditionDetail> conditionDetailList = HelperDataConditionDetail.GetAllData(getApplicationContext(), null, null);

    try {
        int i = 0;
        for(DataConditionDetail dcd : conditionDetailList){

            jsonConditionValue.put("VariableCondition",dcd.get_variableCondition());
            jsonConditionValue.put("Operator",dcd.get_operator());
            jsonConditionValue.put("VariableValue",dcd.get_variableValue());

            if(!strConditionID.equals(dcd.get_conditionId())){
                Integer indexConditionDetail = 0;
                if(!strConditionGroup.equals(dcd.get_groupCondition())){


                    jsonConditionIndex.put(String.valueOf(indexConditionDetail),jsonConditionValue);

                    indexConditionDetail++;
                    strConditionGroup = String.valueOf(dcd.get_groupCondition());
                }
                jsonConditionGroup.put(String.valueOf(dcd.get_groupCondition()),jsonConditionIndex);
                strConditionID = String.valueOf(dcd.get_conditionId());
            }
            jsonConditionDetail.put(String.valueOf(dcd.get_conditionId()),jsonConditionGroup);
        }

        //ApplicationHelper.LogD(String.valueOf(jsonConditionDetail.length()));
        ApplicationHelper.LogD(jsonConditionDetail.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But instead these are my results:

```
"1196":
{
    "1":
    {
        "0": {"VariableValue":"27","Operator":"==","VariableCondition":"74"}
    }
},
"1195":
{
    "1":
    {
        "0": {"VariableValue":"27","Operator":"==","VariableCondition":"74"}
    }
},
"1198":
{
    "1":
    {
        "0":{"VariableValue":"27","Operator":"==","VariableCondition":"74"}
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Writing anything in all-capitals is a good way to make people hate you.

Comment: Can you post whats in the `get_variableCondition()` method? It seems like there could be an error there.

Comment: @dthacker : it's not a method, get_variableCondition() is a getter from my object class

Comment: @fr_r you know a getter is just a short name for a particular kind of method? that's like saying "my car isn't a vehicle, it's a car"